# Samba vulnerability (CVE-2017-7494) patch check

Tags: centos, security, samba

I am running Centos 6.9 with Samba version 3.6.23.  I have yum-cron auto-update enabled.  How can I tell if the patch has been applied for the (CVE-2017-7494) vulnerability?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the change log:

`rpm -q --changelog samba | grep -i cve`